# Matrix transposition using recusrion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix, transpose

Can you please give me some sort of pseudo code for matrix transposition using recursion? If it is in one function that will be great.

PS: This might not be a question but I couldn't find the information anywhere. If you know of a site about pseudo codes for recursion that will be awesome.

Comment: In-place or out-of-place ? Square or rectangular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a square MxM matrix:

```
function transpose (x0, y0, x1, y1)
    if (M > 1)
        transpose (0, 0, M/2, M/2) // A
        transpose (0, M/2, M/2, M) // B
        transpose (M/2, 0, M, M/2) // C
        transpose (M/2, M/2, M, M) // D
        swap blocks B and C
    endif

transpose (0, 0, M, M)
```